# How do I find all the datetimes that happen on a particular date in ruby?

Tags: ruby, date

I have a method which goes through each day of the week:

```
  def dates_week(d, delim)
      "<tr>" + (d.beginning_of_week...(d.beginning_of_week+5)).map do |day|
      "<#{delim}> #{yield(day)} </#{delim}>"
    end.join + "</tr>"

  end
```

For each day of the week, I plug that as an arg into a method (or maybe a named_scope, haven't figured out which), that will then output the .count for :all the emails that have a :date_sent on that date.  However, :date_sent is a date-timestamp, so I can't use == as I have below.

```
  def sent_emails_by_date(date)
    ContactEmail.find(:all, :conditions => "date_sent = '#{date}'"
    " ).count
  end
```

For example, in the View this is what I use:

```
<table class='reports'>
    <%= dates_week(Date.today, "th") {|d| d.strftime("%A")} %>
    <%= dates_week(Date.today, "td") {|d| sent_emails_by_date(d)}%>
</table>
```

How do I find all the emails that fall on the day for the date passed through from the method which loops through a week as shown above?

Comment: What is the format of your `date` parameter?

Comment: <table class='reports'>
 <%= dates_week(Date.today, "th") {|d| d.strftime("%A")} %>
 <%= dates_week(Date.today, "td") {|d| sent_emails_by_date(d)}%>
</table>

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
def send_emails_by_date(date)
  ContactEmail.find(:all, :conditions => { :date_sent => (date.at_beginning_of_day)...(date.end_of_day)).count
end
```